# Mysql 2 Table in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I want to use most voted books's ISBN value in books table

My db->

```
**books-rate**
isbn-rate-user id

**books**
isbn-title-author
```

I write this query but although I have used this query yield 271000 books

```
SELECT * from books 
where books.ISBN IN (SELECT ISBN 
                     FROM 
                       (SELECT 'ISBN' as pis 
                        FROM books-rate 
                        GROUP BY `ISBN` 
                        ORDER BY COUNT(pis) DESC LIMIT 10) as xd)
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? Too many nested subqueries is not efficient and scaleable

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0):

If you need  the top 10 then you could use

```
    SELECT *
    from books 
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  isbn 
            FROM `books-rate` 
            GROUP BY isbn
            ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
            LIMIT 10
    ) t on t.isbn  = books.isbn
```

You should not wrap you columnn name with single quote but use eventually backtics .. and you could avoid  the IN clause using an inner join and last the table name with minus  should be enclosed  with backtics